# Quotient $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by an irreducible and monic polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(X)$ be a monic and irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

What is the nature of the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[X]/ \langle f(X) \rangle$?

Is it a field, an integral domain..

To what is it isomorphic to? (I read that it will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$).

Comment: $X$ is a monic irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Z[X]$ and $\Bbb Z[X]/\langle X \rangle \cong \Bbb Z \not\cong \Bbb Z^2$.

Comment: Sorry @PrudiiArca, I've made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta$ be a root of $f$ in $\mathbb C$. Then $\mathbb{Z}[X]/ \langle f(X) \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}[\theta] \subseteq \mathbb C$ and so is a domain.

However, $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ is not a field because $2$ is not invertible. (Try it!)

Because $f$ is monic, $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ is the set of all polynomial expressions $g(\theta)$ of degree less than $n$, the degree of $f$. (This follows from polynomial divisions; $f$ being monic is key here.) 
In particular, $\mathbb{Z}[\theta] \cong \mathbb Z^n$, as *additive groups*. But not as rings because $\mathbb Z^n$ is not a domain when $n>1$.